# Are there code annotations to constrain XML attribute to an enum values?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, resharper, dtd

In the following piece of XML code the value of the IDFeature and IDView attributes must match the repective enums. Do c# code, DTD, XSD, Visual Studio or Resharper allow to specify this constrain?

```
<MenuEntry Name="Menu_name_Reports"
               IDFeature="23"
               IDView="4" 
               Description=""
               ImagePath="/Resources/Menu/reports.png" />
</MenuEntry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD it is possible to constrain attributes to specific values; for example:

```
<xs:attribute name="IDView">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> <!-- here you can set the base type -->
            <xs:enumeration value="value1"/> <!-- add all possible values here -->
            <xs:enumeration value="value2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="value3"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Here `IDView`'s value can only be "value1" or "value2" or "value3".

Here's an example of how to generate this part of an XSD for all values of an `enum` with `XDocument`:

```
enum Values { value1, value2, value3 };
XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

XDocument x = new XDocument(
    new XElement(xsd + "attribute",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
        new XAttribute("name", "IDView"),
        new XElement(xsd + "simpleType",
            new XElement(xsd + "restriction",
                new XAttribute("base", "xs:string"),
                Enum.GetNames(typeof(Values)).Select(a => 
                    new XElement(xsd + "enumeration", 
                        new XAttribute("value", a.ToString())))))));
```